# Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 problem after debug session on local IIS

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am working on ASP.NET MVC project in Microsoft Visual Studio. When I run project in debug mode on my local IIS server, everything is fine. But when I stop this debug session, I got this problem.

[image]

I had to terminate manually this process. I dont know why is this hapenning. It's not ocurring everytime. Can you help me please? As a browser I am using Google Chrome. Thank you!

Comment: Hi friend, what's exact vs2019 version are you using?

Comment: Please first update VS2019 to latest one and check again, just like [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/436519/vs2019-preview-2-a-64-bit-debugging-operation-is-t.html).

Comment: Hello, I am using version Community 2019. Right now I updated my Visual Studio so I will see if it helps or not. Thanks!

Comment: Hi friend, after you update it to latest 16.4.4, does the issue still persists?

Comment: Hello, yes it still persists.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but it seems I hadn't get the notification from SO...Sometimes windows update version may affect the options in VS. Try updating your windows system if there's any update. Also, please disable all the third-party extensions in VS and restart to check. Maybe you should also try with IE and edge, could the same issue persist?